# Fluid Simulation preview remains static?

Tags: particles, physics, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to make my object melt with Quick Liquid but if i open it in my current project and play it the simulation remains static and doesnt flow, it remains just like in the screenshot below. If i try doing a quick liquid simulation in a different file it works, so it must be something in my file. Does anyone know why this is happening? I haven't found any solutions online.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, the screenshot doesn't show all settings of the domain. Maybe you need to bake the simulation again...?

Comment: if Gordons comment doesn't help, pls provide blend file

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann oops; I added the settings to my question post. and i did bake it again, i also deleted the liquid and the object several times and redid the quick liquid and it didnt change anything.

Comment: How did you actually bake when your _Cache_ is set to _Type_ > _Replay_? There is no _Bake_ button available.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann i set it to All when i baked, but i want to see the preview, that's why it's on replay. when i bake it the fluid is also static.

Comment: Hmmm... then it must be somewhere in the settings of the fluid objects. Or as Chris said, maybe provide your blend file for inspection.

Comment: ...or do you mean, you bake the simulation with _All_ and after baking you switch back to _Replay_ to watch it? This deletes the bake.